# optimise query with calculate field from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables

```
store[store_id(pk),name]
itemsA(item_id(pk),store_id,name)
itemB(item_id(pk),store_id,name)
itemC(item_id(pk),store_id,name)
```

I want a query to retrieve a store and the number of items that he have. something like :

```
select s.store_id ,s.name,count() as numberOfItems from store limit 100
```

what is the optimal query to achieve that with the following restraints :
cannot create a function in the db 
cannot create view
I can only run queries on the db 
Thanks

Comment: You need to use a JOIN.

Comment: @popovitsj you are right , my bad , thanks , I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with correlated subqueries:

```
select s.store_id, s.name,
       ((select count(*) from itemsA a where a.store_id = s.store_id) +
        (select count(*) from itemsB b where b.store_id = s.store_id) +
        (select count(*) from itemsC c where c.store_id = s.store_id)
       ) as numberOfItems
from store s
limit 100;
```

You then want an index in each of the item tables:  `itemsA(stored_id)`, `itemsB(store_id)`, and `itemsC(store_id)`.

The reason this is optimized is because it only has to calculate the values for the arbitrary 100 stores chosen by the `limit`.  And, the calculation can be done directly from the index.  Other approaches will require doing the calculation for all the stores.

Note:  usually when using `limit` you want an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Stores with no items will not show up with this query. If this is a requirement it will have to be tweaked somewhat.

```
SELECT s.store_id, COUNT(*)
FROM Store s
JOIN ItemA a ON a.store_id = s.store_id
JOIN ItemB b ON b.store_id = s.store_id
JOIN ItemC c ON c.store_id = s.store_id
GROUP BY s.store_id
```

A simple modification to also include stores with 0 items:

```
SELECT s.store_id, COUNT(a.store_id) + COUNT(b.store_id) + COUNT(c.store_id)
FROM Store s
LEFT JOIN ItemA a ON a.store_id = s.store_id
LEFT JOIN ItemB b ON b.store_id = s.store_id
LEFT JOIN ItemC c ON c.store_id = s.store_id
GROUP BY s.store_id
```

Comment: @igx I added an extra solution that should handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly

```
DECLARE @store TABLE (store_id INT, name NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @itemsA TABLE (item_id INT,store_id INT, name NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @itemsB TABLE (item_id INT,store_id INT, name NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @itemsC TABLE (item_id INT,store_id INT, name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @store VALUES (1,'Store1')
INSERT INTO @store VALUES (2,'Store2')

INSERT INTO @itemsA VALUES (1,1,'itemsA_item1')
INSERT INTO @itemsA VALUES (2,1,'itemsA_item2')
INSERT INTO @itemsA VALUES (3,1,'itemsA_item3')

INSERT INTO @itemsB VALUES (1,2,'itemsB_item1')
INSERT INTO @itemsB VALUES (2,2,'itemsB_item2')
INSERT INTO @itemsB VALUES (3,2,'itemsB_item3')
INSERT INTO @itemsB VALUES (4,1,'itemsB_item4')


INSERT INTO @itemsC VALUES (1,3,'itemsC_item1')
INSERT INTO @itemsC VALUES (2,3,'itemsC_item2')
INSERT INTO @itemsC VALUES (3,2,'itemsC_item3')

SELECT TOP 100 store_id, SUM(HasItems) AS TotalItems FROM
(
    SELECT store_id, COUNT(name) AS HasItems FROM @itemsA GROUP BY store_id
    UNION
    SELECT store_id, COUNT(name) AS HasItems FROM @itemsB GROUP BY store_id
    UNION
    SELECT store_id, COUNT(name) AS HasItems FROM @itemsC GROUP BY store_id
) AS StoreItems
GROUP BY store_id
```